# Julia equivalent of Ruby's each_cons

Tags: arrays, iterator, julia

In Ruby there's a method `each_cons`, which can be used to iterate over consecutive groups of a given size. For example,

```
irb(main):001:0> [4, 7, 6, 1, 0, 3].each_cons(2) { |x| p x }
[4, 7]
[7, 6]
[6, 1]
[1, 0]
[0, 3]
=> nil
```

Here we're selecting and printing each consecutive pair of elements from the input array.

How would one go about this in Julia?

One could define a function like so:

```
function eachcons(x::Array{Any,1}, n::Int)
    L = length(x)
    (L ≤ 1 || n > L) && return nothing   # Matches Ruby's behavior
    return [x[i-n+1:i] for i = n:L]
end
```

Is there a better or more idiomatic approach than this custom function?

Comment: Note that technically the given function is more like doing `x.each_cons(n).to_a` but ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a pre-made solution, there's always the `partition` function in the [Iterators](https://github.com/JuliaLang/Iterators.jl) package. The function can return a tuple of n consecutive elements from an array:

```
julia> using Iterators
INFO: Precompiling module Iterators...

julia> A = [4, 7, 6, 1, 0, 3]

julia> for pair in Iterators.partition(A, 2, 1)
           println(pair)
       end
(4,7)
(7,6)
(6,1)
(1,0)
(0,3)
```

Comment: I always forget about Iterators. I wonder why those functions aren't included in Base. Oh well. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Some time between when this answer was created and Julia 1.5.2, Iterators.partition lost its three argument form, and now only takes two arguments, so this answer no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter in `Iterators.partition(...)` disappeared which is a shame. Perhaps a new version in a Julia future version could be:

```
Iterators.partition(enum, 3, advance = 1)
```

Anyways, a workaround just now is:

```
julia> zip(enum, enum[2:end], enum[3:end])
```